# How to expand the $\ln(x)$ to Maclaurin series?

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

There was a silly question - how to expand the $\ln{x}$ to Maclaurin series?

Comment: We cannot. The function is not  defined at $0$, and neither are its derivatives.  But we can find a Taylor series about $x=a$ for any positive $a$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nohow. To Maclaurin series can be expanded $\ln{(1 + x)}$ in the neighborhood of zero. $f (x) = \ln{x}$ can't be expanded, at least insofar as $f(0)$ is not defined.

Comment: Oh, sure!! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A power series has to converge at the point which the series is expanded about. $\log(x)$ is not defined at $x=0$ and therefore you cannot have a power series for $\log(x)$ which converges at $x=0$, hence no Maclaurin's series.

Comment: Shame to me... I forgot about ln0 is not defined...